# how to extract xml nodes in c# using xpaths

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

From the following GeoCodeRespose xml how can we extract values of locality, route and street number using xpath in a c# program.

```
<GeocodeResponse> 
<status>OK</status>
 <result>
<type>street_address</type>
<formatted_address>1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA</formatted_address>
<address_component>
<long_name>1600</long_name>
<short_name>1600</short_name>
<type>street_number</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Amphitheatre Pkwy</long_name>
<short_name>Amphitheatre Pkwy</short_name>
<type>route</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Mountain View</long_name>
<short_name>Mountain View</short_name>
<type>locality</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
</result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

so far I can get the xml in the xml document and can get the value of formatted address as below

```
   XmlDocument doc=GetGeoCodeXMLResponse();
   XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(new XmlNodeReader(doc));
   XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

   XPathNodeIterator resultIterator = navigator.Select("/GeocodeResponse/result");
        while (resultIterator.MoveNext())
        {

            XPathNodeIterator formattedAddressIterator = resultIterator.Current.Select("formatted_address");
            while (formattedAddressIterator.MoveNext())
            {
               string FullAddress = formattedAddressIterator.Current.Value;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use an XmlSerializer or LinqtoXml?

Comment: I am open to use XmlSerializer or LinqtoXml if you can kindly give me an example to extract these kind of values from xml

Comment: Is this XML consistent every time you need to deserialize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LinqToXml`, try this, you will get an anonymous type with all the properties you need.

```
 var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

 var result = xDoc.Descendants("result").Select(c =>
              new
              {
                FormattedAddress = c.Element("formatted_address").Value,
                StreetNumber = c.Descendants("address_component")
                        .First(e => e.Element("type").Value == "street_number").Element("short_name").Value,
                Route = c.Descendants("address_component")
                        .First(e => e.Element("type").Value == "route").Element("short_name").Value,
                Locality = c.Descendants("address_component")
                        .First(e => e.Element("type").Value == "locality").Element("short_name").Value
          }).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your XML is consistent, this is probably the easiest way.

Create an object that represents the XML:

```
public GeocodeResponse
{
  public string Status { get; set; }
  public Result Result { get; set; }

  public class Result
  {
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string formatted_address { get; set; }
    // etc..
  }
}
```

Deserializing an object in XML.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GeocodeResponse));
GeocodeResponse geocodeReponse = 
  (GeocodeResponse)serializer.Deserialize(xmlAsString);
```